How to search a text in excel file using Selenium Python
I have some data in an excel file. I want to go to excel file then search a text (taken from website table), then get all the data of that row which will be used to fill table in browser.
Example : I want selenium to search ST0003 then get Name, Father's Name of that student ID, so that I can fill this in college website.

I thought I'll get a student_id from website then paste it in existing excel sheet where I'll fill other details using VLOOKUP but this method doesn't look good.

from where do you access the table in which you want to search? is in a container from a website? is in google sheets? an external locally/or not stored excel file? Can you provide a code example of what you want to do?

if I am correct, your Excel sheet has details(student id, name, father name).
you have to search for some text in Excel and also you need complete row details.
Then what you need to do using selenium ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My suggestion:
import xlrd
with xlrd.open_workbook('your_excel_file') as file:
    sheet = file.sheet_by_index(0)  # switch to the student data sheet
    students = {}
    for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        students[sheet.row_values(i)[0]] = {'name': sheet.row_values(i)[1], 'father_name': sheet.row_values(i)[2]}

Read the content of the excel first and make a dictionary students like
{'ST0003':{'name': 'student 3', 'father_name': 'Name 3'}, 'ST0004': {'name': 'student 4', 'father_name': 'Name 4'}}.
After that, you can fill in the blank on your webpage with selenium like:
student_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath to the student id')  # search and get the student id
blank_to_fill = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath to the blank you wanna fill')  # search and get the table blank you want to fill in
blank_to_fill.send_keys(students[student_id]['name'])  # fill in the blank

